# Use subquery with multiple rows

Tags: sql, subquery

I have been trying to work out code in SQL to clean up a data sheet (more than 200 rows and 50 columns) to add trailing zeros before the decimal point values.

I tried to apply a to_char to convert string data into a 0 padded figure, for all values less than 1

```
select to_char((select "1980" from imf_population where "1980" <1), '0.999')
from imf_population
```

However due to the subquery the to_char cannot perform a conversion on multiple rows returned from the 1980 column as there is more one record whose value is less than 1.

Any tips on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Your to_char must be in, not out. Once in, the outer select is not needed anymore:

```
select to_char("1980",'0.999') from imf_population where "1980"<1;
```

"1980" is a column name, right? (well, sqlite accepted `create table imf_population ("1980" number);` `select "1980" from imf_population;`, but it does not have to_char, I guess you're using oracle)

Comment: Yes, "1980" is a column name. I fixed it by using a case statement
<blink> 
select case when "1980" <1 then to_char("1980", '0.999') else "1980" end from imf_population
<blink>

I then wrapped this into an update statement with set to change the look of the data points... It was just tedious to repeat this for every column. Would you know how I could make a function that would have this to_char statement applied to every single column (of which I have 50)?

Answer (score 0):

> Note : Only Use Lowercase Letters, Numbers, and Underscores when
> naming columns. Use Simple, Descriptive Column Names

> ```
>  CREATE TABLE imf_population (col varchar2(20) )
> ```

> ```
>  INSERT INTO imf_population (col) VALUES ('0.5289')
> ```

> ```
> select to_char(col,'0.999') from imf_population where col<1;
> ```
>
> ```
> | TO_CHAR(COL,'0.999') |
> | :------------------- |
> |  0.529               |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4181336965b6a34a3da22960b6f5b4ae)*